# How to construct an $\epsilon$-ball of $x$ disjoint from the set $A$ where $x \notin A$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a metrizable space with metric $d$, and let $x\in X$ be disjoint from a subset $A$ of $X$. I want to construct an $\epsilon>0$ ball of $x$ which is disjoint from $A$. It seems intuitive that this is possible, just choose $\epsilon>0$ such that for each $a\in A$, $0<\epsilon<d(x,a)$. So that $B_d(x,\epsilon)$ is the desired ball. The problem is that, I am not sure if such an $\epsilon>0$ actually exists; I had the idea that we can just set $\epsilon := \inf \{d(x,a)|a\in A \}$, but I don't know if the infimum of that set is greater than zero. Is my idea correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. It is $0$ iff $x \in \bar A$

Comment: This requires that $x$ is not an element of the closure of $A$ which is not a direct consequence of $x\notin A$.

Comment: It's false if $A$ is not closed: suppose $x\in\bar  A$. Then $d(x,A)=0$.

Comment: I see, if $x \notin \overline{A}$ then there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ disjoint from $A$. So we just choose an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_d(x,\epsilon) \subseteq U$. What about this?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $A=(0,1)$ and $x=0$. Then $x \notin A$, but $d(x,A)=0$. Your idea is correct if $A$ is a closed subset.

Answer (score 0):

You only suppose $x\not\in A$. In order to find $\epsilon>0$ sucht that $B_\epsilon(x)\cap A=\emptyset$, you need that $X\setminus A$ contains an open set containing $x$. For example, if  $A$ is closed, that would be enough (but it is not necessary).